# How to add URL to PDFs with searchable text in python?

Tags: python, pdf

I have several PDF files of scanned old books with searchable text. I'd like to add links to texts matching a pattern. Here are the logical steps:

1 - Find pattern;
2 - Get the position of the text;
3 - Add a link to the text in that position.

For example, every time I find a number with more than 4 digits, I  add a link (square around the text) to a website (in latex I'd simple replace "123123" with "\href{google.com}{123123}". Do you have any idea on how to do that in python or other languages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PYMuPDF is the python library, which is dealing with such stuff. I see an article [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/580765-how-to-maintain-pdf-links-with-fitz-pymupdf/) which is talking about a similar thing. I personally used the PyMuPDF also known as fitz library which works well.